# Is `is_sidebar_active()` deprecated, and showing error?

Tags: functions, sidebar

I **[Googled](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=kKj&rls=en&q=is_sidebar_active&btnG=)** `is_sidebar_active()`, used by several WordPress trainer, but I came to the decision, the function's surely deprecated. But unfortunately I found no mention, even no entry in WordPress Codex.

As a Wikipedian, I also edit the Codex sometime, but need the confirmation that, `is_sidebar_active()` IS DEPRECATED, and `is_active_sidebar()` is ON now.

I used `is_active_sidebar()` instead of `is_sidebar_active()` in my theme and it's working fine.

But I need a confirmation. Anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_sidebar_active()` is not a WordPress function. Do not use that. This is probably a typo.

The correct name is `is_active_sidebar($index)`, and that function is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be deprecated -- but the only solid reference I found to it was in the Theme Trac site (for instance, http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3585 refers to `is_sidebar_active()` being deprecated).  I didn't find `is_sidebar_active()` in the Core Trac, not even in the search.  Google is a little too eager to be helpful, and when I search for `is_sidebar_active()`, most of the hits I got were for `is_active_sidebar()` instead.

Long story short, use `is_active_sidebar()`.